# Coded UI does not pick up a browser window that contains an acrobat reader

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

Coded UI doesn't seem to be picking up a browser window that contains an acrobat reader in it.  I'm Using IE 9.  When i pick up a browser window i'm suppose to click the back button.  This is working until i pull up a window that has a pdf reader in it.

Has anyone run across this issue and how was it handled.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried finding the new window by title? Use the doc/window title as the search property. That's worked for me before.

Comment: While this is an okay answer, it would be better if you provided an example for how to do what you're suggesting.

Comment: Hi @Scott the problem with that is it will fail whenever you go to try to grab the window title.  I've tried the below code 
var myPdFdoc = GlobalVariables.Browser;
var mycurrntWindo = myPdFdoc.CurrentDocumentWindow;
 var TitleCurrntwnd = mycurrntWindo.Container.Name;
It seems to bomb and exception occur of not being able to find the control. Maybe i'm doing it all wrong.